# Regex: how to match repeating pattern incrementally

Tags: regex

Given the following string:

```
one.two.three.four
```

How do I match/capture which results in the following in one go:

```
one
one.two
one.two.three
```

(if it's possible at all)

Comment: Do you mean, have each of those in a separate capturing group in a single match?

Comment: @CertainPerformance well either separate or single capturing group. The number of the '.' is arbitrary though i.e. 'one.two.three.four.five.six' is possible

Comment: Trivially possible in `.NET` flavors, but impossible otherwise, IIRC

Comment: Can you try: `/\b(?=\w*[.]).\w+\b/g`. Look here: https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/37.

Comment: @Sinto not what I'm looking for. Given one.two.three.four it has to match/capture multiple times resulting in 'one' , 'one.two', 'one.two.three'

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(?=(^|(?<=[.]))([\w.]+))
```

This will perform a non-width look ahead, it means that the string will be iterated on character at the time and matching the pattern; inside it says:

Using a non-width look-behind:

- is there the beginning of the string?
- do i have a . behind the cursor?

Using a capture group, it will get the rest of the string that was not consumed yet.

Comment: Almost there! This currently gets it backwards i.e. given 'one.two.three' it results in 'one.two.three', 'two.three', 'three'. Should be 'one.two.three', 'one.two', 'one'.
Im currently trying to understand how this works and fix it myself before accepting your answer.

Comment: Sorry, i miss understand. The string is searched from left to right and there is not so much you can do with regex, but you can pre and post process the string in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: Maybe you can find the indexes of dot chars, and substring repeatedly from start to every index found. Avoiding with this, the use of regex, knowing that will not be performance differences between both approaches in this case.

Comment: Indeed. I have a working solution to my particular problem simply by splitting on '.' character. This is just to satisfy my curiousity :)

Answer (score 0):

### `(\w+)\.?`

`(\w+)` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`+ Quantifier` — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

`\.? Quantifier` —  matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)

if your characters are lowercased alphabets. then try this. `([a-z]+)\.?`

Comment: This is not the expected behaviour